# How to pass Network in OkhttpClient in socketFactory for network request in retorfit

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

```
@Provides
    @PerApplication
    @Named("SocketNetwork")
    fun providesSocketNetwork(context: Context): Network {
        var socketNetwork: Network? = null
        val cm = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val request = NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
            .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
            .build()
            if (cm != null) {
                cm.requestNetwork(
                    request,
                    object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                            socketNetwork = network
                            cm.bindProcessToNetwork(network)
                        }
                    })
            }
        return socketNetwork!!
    }

    @Provides
@PerApplication
@Named("RoveR3OkHttpClient")
fun providesOkHttpClient(context: Context,@Named("SocketNetwork")socketNetwork: Network): OkHttpClient {
    val cacheSize = (5 * 1024 * 1024).toLong()
    val mCache = Cache(context.cacheDir, cacheSize)
    val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .cache(mCache) 
        .socketFactory(socketNetwork.socketFactory)
        .addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor).addInterceptor(TimeHeaderInterceptor())
    return client.build()
}
```

This my code i want to provide @Named("SocketNetwork")socketNetwork: Network) in this way so that it should return Network and that network i could pass in OkHttpClient so that i can do network request using that socket, but i am unable to synchronized onAvailable method in providesSocketNetwork method so its returning null can any one please help me or suggest me some other way  how to do this i am stuck in this issue for long time .

Thanks